# Problem when trying to add a scrolling bar on a frame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I try do add a scrolling bar in my frame, with no success. I have read posts about this subject on stackoverflow and tried many suggestions, but they don't work for me.

I have tried this.

```
import tkinter as tk 

class Interface(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root, width=768, height=576, **kwargs)
        #self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)


        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", 
                                  tags="self.frame")

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
        self.populate()

        def command():
            global parameters
            temp=[entry.get() for entry in self.entries]
            parameters=temp 

        self.bouton_Executer = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Exécuter le programme", fg="red", command=command)
        self.bouton_Executer.place(x=400  ,y= 840)


    def populate(self):        
        self.all_entries= []

        label=tk.Label(self.frame, text="a").place(x = 20, y = 60)
        entry=tk.Entry(self.frame)
        entry.place(x = 60, y = 60)
        self.all_entries.append(entry)

        label=tk.Label(self.frame, text="b").place(x = 20, y = 80)
        entry=tk.Entry(self.frame)
        entry.place(x = 60, y = 80)
        self.all_entries.append(entry)


    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
            #'''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
            self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all")

root = tk.Tk()  
interface = Interface(root)
interface.mainloop()
interface.destroy()
```

I want to have a window with the two widgets a and b, and a scrolling bar (because in the entire code, I have many widgets and all the widgets don't appear on the window).

By creating the object 'interface', no widgets appear in the window and I see the scrolling bar but I can't scroll the window.

Comment: scrolling Frame is not easy so better find examples of existing [ScrolledFrame](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/scrolled-frame-canvas) and use it.

Comment: if you use `pack()` instead of `place()` then it will automatically resize Frame so you will see widgets.

Comment: I used  your class 'scrolledframe' while keeping 'place()' and I didn't see the widgets. Is it 'place' the problem? If so why?

Comment: yes, `place` is the problem. You already have explanation in @BryanOakley answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `pack` or `grid`, the default behavior is for the containing widget to grow or shrink to fit all of its children. `place` does not have this behavior, so when you use `place` to put widgets in a frame, the frame will retain whatever its requested size is. You didn't give the frame a size, so it will default to 1x1 pixels.

It is rarely a good idea to use `place`. Not only for this reason, but also because you have to do all of the work of making sure the layout fits the window, is responsive, and works on machines that may have a different resolution and different fonts.

If you switch to using `grid` or `pack`, your frame will automatically grow to fit all of the widgets contained inside.

Comment: But for each parameter asked to the user, I want to position the typing box in a specific space. How can I do that with grid or pack? For example, how can I write the three following instructions: tk.Label(root, text="b").place(x = 20, y = 80) ; entry=tk.Entry(root) ; entry.place(x = 60, y = 80) , using grid?

Comment: @Ing: how do you define "specific space"? Both `pack` and `grid` give you a lot of control over where to put widgets.`pack` lets you decide the side of the available space (left, right, top, bottom), and `grid` lets you define the row and column. You can still use `pack` if you want by giving the frame an explicit size, but then you have to remember to update that size each time you add more widgets. It's easier to just let `pack` or `grid` do that for you.